# Why movaps causes segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, sse, memory-alignment, att

### Introduction

I was trying to familiarize myself with AES instructions, to then use libraries that make use of these technologies more consciously. However, I don't regularly program in assembly, so I have some confidence with the language, but I don't consider myself an expert. I have written a listing of about 150 assembly lines to try to use these functions using the documentation offered by Intel. However I have not succeeded to make many steps ahead.

The program crashes due to a segmentation error in the main when I use the instruction `movaps`. I've tried debugging with both gdb and valgrind, but it seems like everything should work, but it doesn't. Here are the lines that cause problems.

### Code

```
main:
start_f

    printstr

    movaps (string), %xmm15
==> movaps (key), %xmm0
    call   aes_encript

    movaps %xmm15, string
    printstr

end_f
```

`start_f` and `end_f` are just to macros to start and end the function. I also provide the code for the .data section to show how there should be no problem:

```
    .data
string:
    .string "string"
    .fill   (128 - (.-string)), 1, 0

newline:
    .byte   0x0a

key:
    .fill   128, 1, 0

    .text
    .global _start
```

### Debugging info

As for the error, I couldn't get any useful information either by statically disassembling or in gdb. Valgrind was no help either, which is to be expected since I don't touch the heap at all.
I show a partial listing of the main disassembled in gdb:

```
   0x0000000000401022 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000401023 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000401026 <+4>:     mov    $0x402000,%rsi
   0x000000000040102d <+11>:    call   0x401156 <write_long>
   0x0000000000401032 <+16>:    mov    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000401039 <+23>:    mov    $0x1,%rbp
   0x0000000000401040 <+30>:    mov    $0x402080,%rsi
   0x0000000000401047 <+37>:    mov    $0x1,%rdx
   0x000000000040104e <+44>:    syscall 
   0x0000000000401050 <+46>:    movaps 0x402000,%xmm15
=> 0x0000000000401059 <+55>:    movaps 0x402081,%xmm0
   0x0000000000401061 <+63>:    call   0x4010b6 <aes_encript>
   0x0000000000401066 <+68>:    movaps %xmm15,0x402000
   0x000000000040106f <+77>:    mov    $0x402000,%rsi
   0x0000000000401076 <+84>:    call   0x401156 <write_long>
```

And here is the content at address `0x402081` (which is perfectly accessible):

```
(gdb) x/32x 0x402081
0x402081:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x402091:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020a1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020b1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020c1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020d1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020e1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x4020f1:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

### Request

I don't exclude that the error is something stupidly trivial: I haven't used as for a while. In any case if you could give me a tip I would be grateful.

In case you want to try this code by yourself here is a pastebin with the whole listing: https://paste.debian.net/1194986/

Comment: Either align the data on a 16 byte memory address or use `movups` for unaligned access.

Comment: This is 64-bit code, so you should be addressing static data with RIP-relative addressing modes like `movaps string(%rip), %xmm15`, like a compiler would.  Prefer using XMM0..7 so the machine code can be more compact (REX prefix not needed). 
 Also, typo: encrypt not encript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0x402081` memory address of `key` is not aligned to 16-bytes.

From [Intel® 64 and IA-32 architectures software developer’s manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html#combined), [`MOVAPS` specification](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movaps):

> **MOVAPS—Move *Aligned* Packed Single-Precision Floating-Point Values**
>
> ...
> When the source or destination operand is a memory operand, the operand must be aligned on a 16-byte (128-bit
> version), 32-byte (VEX.256 encoded version) or 64-byte (EVEX.512 encoded version) boundary or a generalprotection exception (#GP) will be generated.

You could use `movups`, but it's usually better to align your constants.

In previous line `0x402000` is aligned to 16 bytes, so previous line doesn't segfault.

`key` could be defined as follows to be aligned to 16 bytes:

```
    .balign 16
key:
    .fill   128, 1, 0
```

Also note, that's 128 *bytes* of zeros, not 128 bits.  And since it's all zero, you could have put it in `.bss` instead of `.data`.

(Put `newline: .byte   '\n'` *after* this, so you don't waste 15 bytes on alignment.  Or better, put newline in `.rodata`, or have `write_long` include a newline in the output it writes.)

Comment: Oh yeah I really didn't see that. Than you very much.

Comment: @Renat: In GAS code, always use `.balign 16` or `.p2align 4`, never the ambiguous `.align`.  On some systems (e.g. MacOS), `.align` is an alias for `.p2align` instead of `.balign`, and you don't to align by 64k.